# can QGIS for Mac OSX 10.6 handle (both read and generate) GeoPDF files?

Tags: qgis, geopdf, mac

I would like to know if QGIS for Mac OSX 10.6 can handle (both read and generate) GeoPDF files. Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 1):

read some information [here](http://briangeekblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/my-latest-odd-project.html) from Brian Maddox. there is some useful information about GeoPDF.

there is no more information about GeoPDF by Qgis for supporting it.

[image: geopdf]

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Since QGIS uses GDAL to read raster files, it depends on your GDAL installation. Default installations of GDAL don't include GeoPDF support because additional PDF libraries (libpoppler or libpodofo) are required.

See also:

- http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html (search for Geospatial PDF) and
- http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html

Due to this requirements I suppose that your QGIS installation can't read (nor write) GeoPDF.

Answer (score 1):

> it depends on your GDAL installation

In [Kyngchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks), you can download the GeoPDF plugin v1.9.1-2  for GDAL 1.9